# EclipseLink: Wrong number or types of arguments calling a Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink for a web project involving EJB 3 and Oracle stored procedures. We're still in the beginning, so I had a simple procedure set up for testing, here's the signature:

```
p_test.testProcedure(as_param in varchar2)
```

Here's the code I use to call the procedure, similar to the Using Basic Query API article on Eclipsepedia:

```
JpaEntityManager jem = (JpaEntityManager) em.getDelegate();

StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
call.setProcedureName("p_test.testProcedure");

call.addNamedArgument("param", "param", String.class);

DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery();
query.setCall(call);

query.addArgument("param", String.class);

Vector<String> values = new Vector<String>();
values.add("test");

jem.getActiveSession().executeQuery(query, values);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of 
arguments in call to 'TESTPROCEDURE' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement
ignored Error Code: 6550 Call: BEGIN p_test.testProcedure(param=>?); END; bind => [test] Query: DataReadQuery()
```

I also have tried setting call argument type to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR and none at all, to no effect.

Someone have any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using a combination of the above two answers and my own wits.

First, I used addNamedArgumentValue asu suggested by #1.
Second, I used the correct procedure parameter name as suggested by #2.
Last, I used directly `jem.executeNonSelectingCall(call)` and it worked. (Also with OUT parameters).

So they both get a vote up!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are specifying a different procedureParameterName in the addNamedArgument method than what is specified in your stored procedure, i.e., "param" vs "as_param".   Try changing your logic to the following:

```
call.addNamedArgument("as_param", "param", String.class);
```

This method maps the parameter name between what is used in your call to query.addParameter and what is defined in the stored procedure.

Comment: Tried that right away: the error is now `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement Error Code: 0 Call: BEGIN p_test.testProcedure(as_param=>?); END; bind => [test] Query: DataReadQuery()`

Comment: Have you verified that the stored procedure executes correctly, i.e., execute it directly from SQL*Plus or another SQL client?

Answer (score 1):

From TopLink docs

**addNamedArgument**

```
public void addNamedArgument(java.lang.String procedureParameterName,
                             java.lang.String argumentFieldName)
```

> PUBLIC: Define the argument to the
>   stored procedure and the
>   field/argument name to be substitute
>   for it. The procedureParameterName is
>   the name of the procedure argument
>   expected. The argumentFieldName is the
>   field or argument name to be used to
>   pass to the procedure. If these names
>   are the same (as they normally are)
>   this method can be called with a
>   single argument.

```
public void addNamedArgumentValue(java.lang.String procedureParameterName,
                                  java.lang.Object argumentValue)

 call.addNamedArgumentValue("param",(Object)values );
```

Comment: That is also on EclipseLink docs. Tried that and I now get `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement Error Code: 0 Call: BEGIN p_test.testProcedure(as_param=>?); END; bind => [test] Query: DataReadQuery()`, same as below, but with different code.